# Changing order of limit and complex derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Assume $f(z,t)$ is complex differentiable at $z=z_0$, $t$ is a real parameter. Under which condition is $\lim_{t \rightarrow t_0} f(z,t)$ also complex differentiable at $z = z_0$?

I know some theorems and their proofs from real analysis, but I was curious whether I could prove the corresponding theorems in the complex domain but I am unsure what the condition of limit switching theorem might be!

**EDIT**

How does the result extends to interchangeability of derivatives? I.e. assume $f(z,t)$ is both $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$ differentiable in some neighborhood of $z_0$ and $t_0$. Under which conditions we have that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is also $z$ differentiable?

**ADDENDUM**
*(Comment to @Bobby Ocean answer)*
Consider a following: Somehow you have proven that $z^t$ is $z$ complex differentiable for each real $t$ (except branches). Then you define a function $g(z) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} (z^t - 1)/t$, how do you **prove** this is also complex differentiable? I would like to define the logaritmic function this way, and proving $g'(z)=1/z$ would require knowing whether I can interchange the derivatives.

Comment: If $t$ is a fixed number $>0$, then $(d/dz) z^t = t\cdot z^{t-1}$. You can write $z^t=e^{t\ln(z)}$ where $ln(z)$ is a branch of the logarithm, if that makes it easier.

Comment: You can define the $z^t$ function without using complex exponential and logarithm as $(r \angle \phi)^t = r^t \angle t\phi$ in polar form. Proving that this is indeed a complex differentiable function is another question, but I assume it can be done easily. Then, without any knowledge of the complex logarithm and exponential function, you can define the logaritmic function as $g(z) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} (z^t - 1)/t$, the problem remains to show whether this definition creates a complex differentiable function, i.e., how would one **prove** it is so?

Comment: In general, "a" logarithm, is any complex valued function $g(z)$ defined on $G$, such that $e^{g(z)}=z$ on $G$. Note, that because the exponential function $e^w$ is never zero, then by assumption, $G$ cannot contain the origin. There are standard proofs that demonstrate that any logarithm is differentiable and has derivative $g'(z)=\frac{1}{z}$. Hence, if you believe $g(z)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{z^t-1}{t}$ is a logarithm, then you only need to show that $e^{g(z)}=z$ for all $z$ in the domain you wish to use; the fact that it is differentiable follows automatically.

Comment: The complex exponential function $e^z$ would first have to be defined though. I am well aware that $e^z$ can be defined via the Taylor series or the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+z/n)^n$ valid for any complex $z$. However, I thought it can be done the other way around, defining the logaritmic function first and then the exponential function as its inverse. First you would have to make sense what does it even mean. The natural assumption is to define logarithm as a function $g(z)$ for which $g' = 1/z$. To keep the introduction elementary, $g$ can be obtained from differentiating $z^t$

Comment: Complex variable theorems are not simply parallels of real analysis theorems (they are extensions). There are similarities, but in general when you begin a course in complex analysis, you are to assume all the theorems of calculus and real analysis. Take for example, "If $f(z)$ is differentiable on $G$, then $f(z)$ is infinitely differentiable on $G$"; this statement holds for complex variable functions but fails for real variable functions. There is no possible "parallel" explanation for this statement from the study of real variables.

Comment: My point is that I have seen a number of books define the Log(x) function and then proceed to define $e^x$ as the inverse, and hence collective provide many simple proofs of real analysis statements. I do not believe there is any parallel to complex variables here; other than the restricted cases. Take for example, the fact that $e^z$ is a periodic function; hence, $e^z$ has infinitely many distinct inverses. This is sharp contrast to the real variable case where $e^x$ is a 1-1 function.

Comment: I have not stated I am using parallel assumptions. See this argument: When the function $z^t$ is defined as the polar form definition I have mention before, it has a natural branch cut at positive real axis. Since we have $z^t = r^t(\cos t\varphi + i \sin t\varphi)$, you get that $g = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} (z^t - 1)/t = \ln r + i\varphi$. Defining the complex exponential function as its inverse, you get that $e^{a+bi} = e^b(\cos b + i \sin b)$, which turns out to be complex differentiable at branch as well. I thought this introduction is clearer than the usual $e^z$ Taylor series or the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The existence of a pointwise limit at the point $t_0$ is insufficient to guarantee a differentiable function.** In general, one needs uniform convergence to preserve various properties like differentiation, integration, continuity, etc.

A simple example would be $f(z,t):=z^t$ on $t>0$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}-\text{B}$ (where $\text{B}$ is some branch cut). Note, $f(z,t)$ is real-differentiable in $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and complex-differentiable in $z\in\mathbb{C}-\text{B}$. Notice, for each fixed $z$ we have, $$h(z):=\lim_{t\to 0} f(z,t) = \left\{\matrix{1 & z\neq 0 \\ 0 & z = 0}\right.$$ a function that is clearly not differentiable at $z=0$.

---

**The the ability to interchange derivatives is not the same thing as the existence of the derivatives.** Not only must you assume that the function is $C^2$ ([example where $f_{xy}(0,0)\neq f_{yx}(0,0)$ because we don't have $C^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Requirement_of_continuity)), but you must also assume that the mixed partials already exist. You are not guaranteed the mixed partial derivatives will even exist, simply because the function is $C^2$. Let me say it another way, $C^2$ isn't good enough to allow you to take mixed partial derivatives.

Explicitly, $f(z,t)$ could be infinitely differentiable with respect to variables $t$ and $z$, and yet $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(z,t)$ could fail to exist at some point in $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{R}$. This is simply another way of saying that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(z,t)$ could fail to be differentiable with respect to $z$ at some point $z_0$. Or as I will show by way of example, $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(z,t)$ could still be a discontinuous function with respect to the variable $z$.

Example.

To be clear, this is a non-obvious example that took me awhile to construct. First we define for each $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, $$g_\alpha(z) := \left\{\matrix{(e^{\alpha z}-1)/z & z\neq 0 \\ \alpha & z=0}\right\} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\alpha^k}{k!}z^{k-1}$$ Note that this is a family of entire functions that are infinitely differentiable in $z$ everywhere in $\mathbb{C}$ (this is easily seen, since the power series representation has an infinite radius of convergence). Now define, $$f(z,t) := \left\{\matrix{t\cdot g_{-1/t^2}(z) & t\neq 0 \\ 0 & t=0}\right.$$ Astonishingly $f(z,t)$ is infinitely differentiable with respect to $t\in\mathbb{R}$ (including at the point $0$), likewise, $f(z,t)$ is infinitely differentiable with respect to $z\in\mathbb{C}$ (again, including the point at $0$) (literally, for each fixed $t$, $f(z,t)$ is entire). However, when we attempt to mix partial derivatives we will get a problem, take $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(z,t) = \left\{\matrix{2e^{-z/t^2}/t^2 + g_{-1/t^2}(z) & t\neq 0 \\ -1/z & t=0}\right.$$ Hence, $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(z,t) = -\frac{1}{z}$$ a clearly discontinuous function in the variable $z$, with no derivative at zero. Thus, even though $f(z,t)$ was infinitely differentiable at $t=0$ with respect to the variable $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and is infinitely differentiable at $z=0$ with respect to the variable $z\in\mathbb{C}$, that meant nothing in determining if $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(z,t)$ would be differentiable with respect $z$ at $z=0$ when $t=0$. We even point out that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(z,t)$ is differentiable with respect to $z$ at $z=0$ for any $t\neq 0$.

Please note that the reason this example works is because we can utilize the "infinitely real-differentiable flat function" $e^{-1/t^2}$. Such function is not complex-differentiable at zero, even though it is real-differentiable at zero. The above example would not apply to multi-variate complex-differentiable functions, $f(z,w)$, that would be a different discussion.

Comment: I strongly appreciate your answer, your counterexamples are very instructive and educative. However, I still lack an insight in assumptions of the interchangeability. Consider a following: Somehow you have proven that $z^t$ is $z$ complex differentiable for each real $t$ (except branches). Then you define a function $g(z) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} (z^t - 1)/t$, how do you **prove** this is also complex differentiable? (I would like to define the logaritmic function this way, and proving $g'(z)=1/z$ would require knowing whether I can interchange the derivatives) [I have added this into q.]

Comment: Not following what you are asking, the two examples I gave are very different from each other. The second one does not have any branch cuts and is defined everywhere and differentiable everywhere. Specifically, I did not define $(z^t-1)/t$, I defined $t(e^{-z/t^2}-1)/z$.

Comment: Yes, you have not defined $g$ as $(z^t - 1)/t$, it is just another example function.

Comment: @BobbyOcean  "You are not guaranteed the mixed partial derivatives will even exist, simply because the function is $C^2$. Let me say it another way, $C^2$ isn't good enough to allow you to take mixed partial derivatives." You may be confused about the definition of $C^2.$ To say a function $f$ belongs to $C^2$ of some open set in $\mathbb R^n$ simply means all second order derivatives of $f$ exist and are continuous in $U.$ This includes mixed partial derivatives of $f.$

Comment: @zhw Yes, I was misunderstanding that. I was under the impression that we are discussing the nuances of when a second partial derivative would exist. The OP asked "Under which conditions we have that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is also z differentiable?" It would seem that assuming $C^2$ (the correct definition) would be simply assuming the conclusion. Right?

Comment: @BobbyOcean From $C^2$  we get $\partial f/\partial t$ is $C^1$ just by definition. You still need to show $\partial f/\partial t$ is complex differentiable, i.e. $Df=0$ as in my answer.

Comment: @zhw Ah, yes, good point. That makes sense now.

Comment: I'm getting

$$f(-1,t)= t\left(\frac{e^{1/t^2}-1}{-1}\right)$$

which blows up at $t=0.$

Comment: Do you still think your example works?

Comment: @zhw. Agreed. It appears I was too quick to assume differentiable in t for every z. Might need to limit to z with Re positive.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is in response to your second question: "Under which conditions we have that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is also $z$ differentiable?"

Suppose $U$ is open in $\mathbb C$ and $g:U\to \mathbb C.$ Assume $g\in C^1(U).$ Define the operator

$$D=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}.$$

Then $g$ is analytic in $U$ iff $Dg\equiv 0$ in $U.$ This follows easily from the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Now suppose $f:U\times I\to \mathbb C$ with $f\in C^2(U\times I).$ (Here $U$ is open in $\mathbb C$ and $I$ is open in $\mathbb R.$) This is your $f(z,t)$ here. Think of $z=x+iy.$

Assume that for fixed $t,$ $f$ is complex differentiable in $z.$ The $C^2$ hypothesis implies switching the order of derivatives in $x,y,t$ leaves the result unchanged. Thus

$$D\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x+iy,t) =  \frac{\partial}{\partial t} Df(x+iy,t).$$

By hypothesis, the inner partial derivative on the right is $0$ for all $(z,t)\in U\times I.$ Hence the left side vanishes identically. This proves $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} f(z,t)$ is analytic in $U$ for each fixed $t.$

Thus $C^2$ smoothness (in the real sense) is a sufficient condition for $\partial f/\partial t $ to be complex differentiable with respect to $z.$

Comment: I believe that is what the OP is asking. If you drop the assumption of $C^2$ and instead only have analytic for $z$ and differentiable for $t$, then can you still conclude the second partial derivatives exist at $(z_0,t_0)$. This does not appear to be obvious to me.

Comment: There are two questions I would like to address. How exactly $C^2$ implies the interchangeability of derivatives and the second one: Can I do better that $C^2$ assumption?

Comment: @Machinato  The interchangeability of derivatives for $C^2$ functions is very well known. See https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/105Sp10/scribe/bgfinal2.pdf

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Yes indeed, thanks. I'll edit. In fact I'm going to get rid of the $1/2$ as well because we don't need to get into that here. Thanks again.